# Let $(X_n)$ be an Ergodic Markov chain, then is $(Y_n)=(X_n,X_{n-1})$ also a Markov Chain, if so what are the transition probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ be an Ergodic Markov chain with limting probabilities $\pi$, then is $(Y_n)=(X_n,X_{n-1})$ also a Markov Chain, if so what are the transition probabilities and $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(Y_n = (i,j))$

For the Markov Property:

$P(Y_n =(i,j) \mid Y_0, ... Y_{n-1}) = P[ (X_n,X_{n-1}) = (i,j) \mid (X_0, \cdot),..., (X_{n-1},X_{n-2})]  \\ = P[(X_n,X_{n-1} = (i,j) \mid (X_{n-1}, X_{n-2})] $

This is where I am not completely clear seems seems to be $P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1}=j)$ at the end of the above string of inequalities.

If this is the case then yes seems it is a Markov chain. And this makes it seem that the transition probabilities as well ass the above limit are the same as the original Markov chain $(X_n)$.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me. Are you unsure about the last step, if it is possible to justify this step?

Comment: @delivery101 yes, it seems to reduce to the original Markov Chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\Big((X_n, X_{n-1}) = (x_n', x_{n-1}') | (X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) = (x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}),
\dots, (X_2, X_1) = (x_2,x_1)\Big) = 0 = 
\mathbb{P}\Big((X_n, X_{n-1}) = (x_n', x_{n-1}') | (X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) = (x_{n-1}, x_{n-2})\Big)
\end{align*}
if $x_{n-1} \neq x_{n-1}'$ and otherwise we have:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\Big(&(X_n, X_{n-1}) = (x_n', x_{n-1}') | (X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) = (x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}),
\dots, (X_2, X_1) = (x_2,x_1)\Big) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\Big(X_n = x_n', X_{n-1} = x_{n-1} | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},\dots, X_1 = x_1\Big) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\Big(X_n = x_n' | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},\dots, X_1 = x_1\Big) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\Big(X_n = x_n' | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2} \Big) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\Big(X_n = x_n', X_{n-1} = x_{n-1} | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2}\Big) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\Big((X_n, X_{n-1}) = (x_n, x_{n-1}) | (X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) = (x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}) \Big)
\end{align*}

Comment: This means the transition probabilities would now have the the requirement that they are now 0 if $x_{n-1} \neq x'_{n-1}$ as you have above? For the limiting probability would it be helpful to write it as a double limit?

Comment: Yes, so the transition probabilities are equivalent to those of the original MC, but now with the requirement that $x_{n-1} = x_{n-1}'$, otherwise the transition probability is 0.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your double limit? I assume you will take limit from $n$ to $\infty$ but what will your second limit be?

Comment: Something like $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m \to n-1} P((x_n,x_m))$ ? Maybe that doesn't make sense, it seems the limiting probabilities would more or less be the same as the original just not sure how to write it.

Comment: I don't think the double limit makes sense here. Can you show what you tried when just taking one limit? I think that when you try to rewrite that limit in terms of a limiting probability of $X_n$ you'll get your result.